# mysql query with multiple not criteria

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Hi I have a query which is working but I would like to remove certain values from the results.

At the moment I have `WHERE (pafaddresses.CountryName !="England")` but I would like this to be Where is not England and where is not Wales, I cannot get it to work for two != statements, I have tried Where !="England" or "Wales", without any success.

Any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT
visits.VisitPk,
visits.ClientFk,
visits.ClientSiteFk,
visits.AssessorFk,
visits.VisitStartDate,
visits.VisitEndDate,
visits.Duration,
visits.VisitStatus,
visits.TargetDate,
CONCAT(MONTHNAME(TargetDate), ' ', YEAR(TargetDate)) AS TargetMonth,
pafaddresses.PostCode,
visits.`Long`,
visits.Lat,
pafaddresses.id,
pafaddresses.CountryName,
CONCAT(Clients.ClientName, ', ', clientsites.SiteName, ', ', MONTHNAME(TargetDate)) AS Description
FROM visits
INNER JOIN clientsites ON visits.ClientSiteFk = clientsites.ClientSitePk
LEFT OUTER JOIN pafaddresses ON clientsites.ActualPAF = pafaddresses.id
INNER JOIN Clients ON visits.ClientFk = Clients.ClientPk
WHERE (pafaddresses.CountryName !="England")
ORDER BY visits.TargetDate, visits.VisitStartDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that either with

```
WHERE (pafaddresses.CountryName != 'England' AND pafaddresses.CountryName != 'Wales')
```

or

```
WHERE pafaddresses.CountryName NOT IN ('England', 'Wales')
```

Comment: @user5641678 Good to hear, in that case you should accept the answer ;)